# .htaccess - won't add www to only one subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess in root directory, with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I go to http://domain.com/subdir it rewrites to http://www.domain.com/subdir.

But I have a problem with one subdirectory named "crm" - if I go to http://domain.com/crm it redirects me to http://www.domain.com instead of http://www.domain.com/crm.

In this "crm" subdirectory I have another .htaccess file, which rewrites .php extension to .html. Here is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone please tell me how can I make this work? So when I will go to http://domain.com/crm it will redirect me to http://www.domain.com/crm.

EDIT:

Root .htaccess was ok, I was changing something and forgot to remove comments for stackoverflow.

crm/.htaccess is now:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteOptions Inherit 

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

But it still doesn't redirect this subdir to www.domain.com/crm but only to www.domain.com :(

Comment: I think the problem is the `.htaccess` file in the `crm` directory that is the problem. I can't see how it rewrites php to html since it's checking for `*.html` and if it matches forward it to `?name=$1&id=$2`. I don't quite understand it. Also you probably want to remove the `#` from the root file. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change root `.htaccess` to this: (seems to be commented at present)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then in crm/.htacess add this line just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

**UPDATE:** Your `crm/.htaccess` is faulty. Replace that content with code from below:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteOptions Inherit 

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Once this code is there redirect will happen as expected.

Comment: Root .htaccess was ok, I was changing something and forgot to remove comments for stackoverflow.

crm/.htaccess is now:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ ?name=$1&id=$2 [L]

But it still doesn't redirect this subdir to www.domain.com/crm but only to www.domain.com :(

Comment: pls post this code in your question, as it is very difficult to read from comments.

Comment: sorry. added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: Thanks. I am using mobile at present, will attend as soon as I get back.