# www RewriteRule not applying to subdirectories with other RewriteRules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess file in my root folder to redirect non-www accesses to www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/$0 [L,R=301]
```

The rule works fine, but in a subdirectory (call it `/sub`) where I have another `.htaccess` file with rewrite rules - the www rule is not applied.

Of course I can copy paste it - but that is obviously not the best solution.

I've tries adding `RewriteOptions Inherit` to the subdirectory's `.htacces` - and the rule works, but the rules works in relation to the sub folder and not the sub folder so *http://example.com/sub/something.html* is redirected to *https://www.example.com/something.html* (removing the `sub` folder from the path)

Setting `RewriteBase /` in the subdirectory's htaccess isn't good as well - since it interferes the other rules I have in the file

I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you have `RewriteBase /` at the beginning of the root `.htaccess`?

Comment: @johnwait No I didn't. I tried adding it now but still `http://example.com/sub/something.html` is redirected to `https://www.example.com/something.html`

Comment: I asked because without it it should have worked. Does the `RewriteRule` work better with subfolders (having `RewriteOptions Inherit` in their `.htaccess`) when using in the root `.htaccess` the part `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `/$0`, as in `RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`? Or else, maybe the child `.htaccess` is faulty. You might want to take a look at that related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980710/htaccess-wont-add-www-to-only-one-subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

By default sub directory's .htaccess doesn't inherit rules defined in parent .htaccess. To enforce this behavior you need to insert this line in `/sub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

before `RewriteEngine On` line.

[Read more about `RewriteOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)

Though keep in mind that parent .htaccess rules are only applied after your current .htaccess rules and there is no way to change this behavior in Apache 2.2 at least. If this is affecting you then you will need to copy `www` rule and place it above your other rules in `/sub/.htaccess`.

**EDIT:** Also change your root `https` rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Also, docs state the following: `Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied **after** rules specified in the child scope.`, if it can be related to your case.

Comment: @johnwait: Thanks, very valid point that I should have mentioned earlier. (Its added in answer now)

Comment: TNX for your reply, but this still doesn't work... ='